# Why Java JDBC connection pool is verified at deployment time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

Why Java JDBC connection pool is verified at deployment time?

I have problem while deploying my Java EE application (.ear). Problem is connected with JDBC Connection Pool which I am using in my app. I can not deploy application on server. This is what I get on console:

```
WARNING: RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool oracle_PROD_Pool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Wyjątek we-wy: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
WARNING: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ oracle_PROD_Pool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Wyjątek we-wy: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
WARNING: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Wyjątek we-wy: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection]
SEVERE: Local Exception Stack:
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Wyjątek we-wy: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Error Code: 0...
```

Then I get SQLException stack trace and and deployment is failed.

I know that it is because of database server is not accessible and connection can not be created, but I would like to deploy app anyway and get SQLException at "app using time". 
This is my jdbc connection pool definition:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
                          associate-with-thread="false" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
                          connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
                          datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource" 
                          fail-all-connections="true" 
                          idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
                          is-connection-validation-required="true" 
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
                          lazy-connection-association="false" 
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
                          match-connections="false" 
                          max-connection-usage-count="0" 
                          max-pool-size="32" 
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
                          name="oracle_PROD_Pool" 
                          non-transactional-connections="false" 
                          pool-resize-quantity="2" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" 
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
                          steady-pool-size="8" 
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="true">
        <property name="User" value="user"/>
        <property name="DatabaseName" value="PROD"/>
        <property name="Password" value="pass"/>
        <property name="DataSourceName" value="OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"/>
        <property name="ServerName" value="172.27.0.101"/>
        <property name="DriverType" value="thin"/>
        <property name="ExplicitCachingEnabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="MaxStatements" value="0"/>
        <property name="NetworkProtocol" value="tcp"/>
        <property name="ImplicitCachingEnabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.27.0.101:1521:PROD"/>
        <property name="PortNumber" value="1521"/>
        <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
```

and associated jdbc resource:

```
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/oraclePROD" object-type="user" pool-name="oracle_PROD_Pool"/>
```

This problem occurs after I migrated to new version of GlassFish server 3.1.2.2. Earlier I have been using glassFish 3.1.1 (build 12) and there was not problem with deployment, I mean connection pool wasn't checked and populated at deployment time, it has place when my application was trying to execute code getting data from database using connection from depicted jdbc connection pool.

I am bit frustrated about that. Is there any way to disable creating and populating jdbc connection pool at deployment time ? Thank you in advance for any help.
--Jaroslaw

Answer (score 0):

A connection pool, as you perceive, is not an API. It's also not a bean which can be initialized on demand. The server is trying to create a pool of connections at server start time. It's like creating a thread pool after server starts up. For any application, that uses a database to function, it is always recommended to create and initialize the pool at server start up.

If you really need you application to be decoupled from the DB connection Pool, *you need to isolate the DB Connection Service in your application as an API.* Meaning, do not use DB connection as a service, but as an API.

This will put the onus on the application to initialize the service when it seems fit.

Comment: I may have overseen the *glassfish* part. Pardon my blunder.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the connection pool to create connections by setting the minimum/initial connection pool size to zero. Check the documentation specific to your connection pool and App Server. For Apache Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool this is "initialSize", for the Oracle Universal Connection Pool this might be "minPoolSize". Sometimes it might be difficult to track down the exact setting, as in some cases, connection pools are setup through a web admin console.